# WP e-commerce: How to select the shipping costs calculation method according to delivery location

Tags: e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

commerce experts,

I'm developing an e-commerce website using WordPress and WP e-commerce.
All works fine but I have a little problem.

I would like to select the shipping costs calculation method according to delivery location:

- if the delivery location is local I would use the "Table rate" method
- if the delivery location is internation I would use the "Flat rate" method

How can I add this feature?
Is there an extension (also commercial)?
Alternatively, where can I edit the PHP code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Things may be slightly different depending on whether you are using the most recent version of wp e-commerce (I think its 3.8 something) - but it's similar in 3.7

In the shipping settings you can choose Flat Rate and then hit edit and set the shipping rates for continental US as well as other continents.

Table rate refers to specific shipping rates related to a certain product, rather than its destination.

There's also a new(ish) plug in for setting other various fixed rates of shipping that you can find ->> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce-fixed-rate-shipping/

Hope this helps you some

Comment: I've found the solution!
It's avalaible a plugin that is simply an example of a custom shipping module: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce-sample-shipping-module/
I've edited this module and I've customized shipping policy.